# NullPointerException when populating a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

According to my compiler I am getting a `NullPointerException` on `chart[rowcount][columncount] = seat;` but I have initialized the seat variable in the line before. I am trying to create a multivariable array of seats and populate it with the seats using the for loops. I had just asked a question about this and thought I understood how to avoid these but I guess not. How am I can I fix this nullPointerException?

```
    public class SeatChart {

private Seat chart[][];

SeatChart(double input[][]) {
    Seat seat;
    for (int rowcount = 0; rowcount < input[0].length; rowcount++) {
        for (int columncount = 0; columncount < input[1].length; columncount++) {
            seat = new Seat(input[rowcount][columncount]);
            chart[rowcount][columncount] = seat;
        }

    }
}



public String buySeat(int row, int column) {
    try {
        chart[row][column].markSold();
        return "Seat [" + row + "]" + "[" + column + "] was purchased.";
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return "The seat your tried to purchase does not exist.";
    }
}

public String buySeat(double price) {
    int k = 0;

    for (int rowcount = 0; rowcount < chart[0].length; rowcount++) {
        for (int columncount = 0; columncount < chart[1].length; columncount++) {
            if (k == 0) {
                if (chart[rowcount][columncount].getPrice() == price) {
                    chart[rowcount][columncount].markSold();
                    return "Seat [" + rowcount + "]" + "[" + columncount + "] was purchased.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "There was an error, please try again";
}

}
```

Comment: Just a pointer: There are compile time errors and runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fill the array `chart` before it is initialized (and is `null`). Array initialization should come somewhere before this statement:

```
chart[rowcount][columncount] = seat;
```

One possible location for initialization is beginning of the `SeatChart` constructor. There you can use size of the `input` array to set size of `chart`:

```
SeatChart(double input[][]) {
    chart = new Seat[input.length][input[0].length];
    // ...
}
```

It is worth mentioning is that `input[0].length` gives the length of *first row* which is number of *columns* in a rectangular array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory both for `this.chart` and for every `this.chart[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set value on following declaration.

```
private Seat chart[][];
```

You need to initialize `Seat` as:

```
private Seat chart[][];

 SeatChart(double input[][]) {
    chart[][]=new Seat[input[0].length][input[1].length];
          //this initialization is needed to avoid NPE. 
 }
```

Comment: `input[0].length` is **not** the row count, it is just the number of elements in the first row. So this code still will throw an `NPE` if ìnput` has more rows than columns (in the first row).